# Change font in php

Tags: php, css

I am trying to change the font of the php section of a website to use a `googlefont`. I have tried various css options and style option but nothing seems to work. Can anyone please share some ideas. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>View Records</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    /* 
    VIEW.PHP
    Displays all data from 'players' table
    */

    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

    // get results from database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `MEN - IAAF WORLD CHAMPIONSHIPS` WHERE 1") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>EVENT</th> <th>ATHLETE 1</th> <th>PERFORMANCE</th> <th>ATHLETE 2</th><th>PERFORMANCE</th><th>ATHLETE 3</th><th>PERFORMANCE</th>      <th></th></tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<font size='18' face='Arial'><tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['Event'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Athlete1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Performance1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Athlete2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Performance2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Athlete3'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Performance3'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';

    echo "</tr>"; 
    } 

    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you define the CSS styles, and how did you target the PHP-generated elements to set those styles?

Comment: I solved it:
'code'<style>
.format {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  font: normal 20px/1 "Abel", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #161616;
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="format">'code'

Comment: Please either select one of the answers given below as being a solution to your question, or (if none of the answers solves your original question) post your actual solution as an answer and accept that as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the font and then use it somewhere. You just imported Abel font there but you are not using it.

Best way to use a google font is defining a new .css file like this

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel);

.newfont {

font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;

}
```

then you only need to use the tag defined there in the elements you want. In your example:

```
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Event'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Athlete1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Performance1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Athlete2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Performance2'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Athlete3'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>" . $row['Performance3'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='newfont'>"<a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>";

echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

or you can just apply that class to the body if you want to use that font everywhere.

---

PD: You need to create the new css file and then you need to call it from the header of .php file you want to use it.

example:

```
<link href="styles/newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add `font-family: Abel, serif` to your css file?

If you want this font to be site wide:

```
body{
  font-family: Abel, serif;
}
```

EDIT: I didn't see a link to a css stylesheet of your own there. If you just need this one style change you can put that body css change in style tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a CSS selector or simply edit it inline using `style` on your `<tr>` tag like so:

```
echo '<tr style="font-family: 'Arial'; font-size: 18px">';
```